# for loop re-adds latest item to all previous positions in NSMutableArray iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am stuck on this problem for already 5 hours. What happens seems so illogical, but when I add an item to NSMutableArray, it also replaces all previous items with it, and I don't know how or why. Here is the EDITED code:

```
NSMutableArray* action = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
BackendlessDataQuery *query = [BackendlessDataQuery query];

for (int i = 0; i<self.categoryNames.count; i++) 
{

    query.whereClause = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"category = \'%@\'", self.categoryNames[i]];
    BackendlessCollection *collection = [backendless.persistenceService find:[ActionCreation class] 
                                                                   dataQuery:query];
    [action removeAllObjects];
    for (int j=0; j<collection.data.count; j++) 
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionaryToInsert = @{ 
                       @"nameAction"  : [collection.data[j] nameAction],
                       @"nameCompany" : [collection.data[j] nameCompany],
                       @"action_start": [collection.data[j] action_start],
                       @"action_end"  : [collection.data[j] action_end],
                       @"address"     : [collection.data[j] adress]     };
        [action insertObject:dictionaryToInsert atIndex:j];
    }
    //NSLog(@"CAtegory Actions %@", action);

    [self.sampleData insertObject: @{   @"category": self.categoryNames[i],
                                        @"actions" : action                 }.mutableCopy                 
                          atIndex:i];

     //NSLog(@"Categories %@", self.sampleData);

}
NSLog(@"-------------------------------");
NSLog(@"sampleData %@", self.sampleData);
```

After

```
[self.sampleData insertObject:@{ @"category": self.categoryNames[i],
                                 @"actions" : action                 }.mutableCopy 
                      atIndex:i];
```

every item in array  changes to the added one.

The output shows that all items in array, are the same and are the latest added. Thank you for any help.

Comment: why are you calling `[action removeAllObjects];` in your inner loop every time? you're going to end up with an action array with only the very last elements after that loop finishes

Comment: wrong code, its meant to be before beginning of for loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your code, you make it clear it is "EDITED code" so some of the errors may be introduced by that - we've no way of knowing. That said:

```
NSMutableArray* action = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Here you create a new empty mutable array `action`

```
BackendlessDataQuery *query = [BackendlessDataQuery query];

for (int i = 0; i<self.categoryNames.count; i++) {

query.whereClause = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"category = \'%@\'", self.categoryNames[i]];
BackendlessCollection *collection = [backendless.persistenceService find:[ActionCreation class] dataQuery:query];

    for (int j=0; j<collection.data.count; j++) {
```

You loop a number of times...

```
        [action removeAllObjects];
```

and each time you empty `action`...

```
         NSDictionary *dictionaryToInsert = @{ @"nameAction"  : [collection.data[j] nameAction],
                       @"nameCompany" : [collection.data[j] nameCompany],
                       @"action_start": [collection.data[j] action_start],
                       @"action_end"  : [collection.data[j] action_end],
                       @"address"     : [collection.data[j] adress]};
        [action insertObject:dictionaryToInsert atIndex:j];
```

and then attempt to add an item to it.

In this version of your code this will fail on the second iteration as you cannot use `insertObject:atIndex:` at anything other than an existing index or one past the highest index. As you empty the array in each iteration the only valid index is `0`, so on the second iteration with an index of `1` you'll get an exception.

You presumably did not intend to empty the array on each iteration. Also it would be simpler for you to just use `addObject:` to fill up `action`.

```
    }
    [self.sampleData insertObject:[@{@"category": self.categoryNames[i],
                                     @"actions" : action} mutableCopy] atIndex:i];
```

Here you add `action` to a dictionary, make a mutable copy of that dictionary, and add
that to `self.sampleData`.

The method `mutableCopy` (and `copy`) makes a *shallow copy* of an object - what you get is a new dictionary but the objects in the dictionary itself are **not** themselves copied.

So your copy also contains references to the same objects as `self.categoryNames[i]` and `action`, and this in turn means *every* entry in `self.sampleData` contains a dictionary whose key `actions` refers to *exactly the same* array. As you go around your loops, empty the `action` array, fill it up again you are changing the array shared by every dictionary you've added - hence the result you are seeing.

```
}
```

To fix your code you should move the declaration of `action` to inside the first loop, remove the `removeAllObjects`, and remove the `mutableCopy`. That way you will create a new array for each collection, fill it, and add it to `self.sampleData`. (You can also switch to using `addObject:`, but that is not needed.)

HTH

Comment: That was amazing analysis of my code)) Thank you very much. It not only solved my problem, but I really understood the problem! Thank you very much good sir!)